# which log file or how do I locate this log file?

Tags: linux, bash, logging, dd

I have perhaps a dumb question, but this might be an easy point...
so i run a dd command at the console and I get a message when it is done like:

```
 0+1 records in
 0+1 records out
 424 bytes (424 B) copied, 0.0191003 s, 22.2 kB/s
```

The question is, which log file or record file is this info stored in?  To be CLEAR, I need to access the above message and not the output file.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about the file being created by `dd`, it's either going to be whatever file you specified with the `of=` option, or standard output, possibly redirected.

That's the way `dd` works: it writes to standard output by default but you can override this by specifying the output file explicitly.

For example:

```
pax> dd if=testprog.c of=/dev/null
6+1 records in
6+1 records out
3454 bytes (3.5 kB) copied, 8.3585e-05 s, 41.3 MB/s
```

---

If you're after the actual status output of the `dd` command rather than the file being copied, `dd` is simply writing this to standard *error,* so you can capture it with:

```
dd if=somfile of=someotherfile 2>dd.stderr
```

This will send standard error through to the file `dd.stderr`. If you *don't* redirect it, then it's almost certainly gone to your default standard error which tends to be your terminal. The only way to get it from there is to cut and paste it with your terminal program. As far as the file system is concerned, it's gone.

Comment: Hi Pax  This did NOT answer my question.  I need to access the actual message "n+n records..." and not the output file.  I assumed it was written to a log somewhere but I can't find it.  am I missing something here?

Comment: I found the answer to my question....
the script command can be used to capture the console output. 

$script filename

Comment: @user3738926, sorry, it wasn't originally clear that you wanted the actual status message from `dd`. No, it's not written to a log file anywhere, it's simply written to standard error, and you can redirect that to a file. See the updated answer.